# Jmeter request to google

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Need a help! 
Using the JMeter need send request to https://www.google.com.ua/imghp?hl=ru&tab=wi&authuser=0 something like a "cat" or "dog" 
and make assertion of one of the finding images. 
Please help!

Comment: Feels like a homework question....

Comment: something like that :)
need use JMeter in work, so that's why asking help.

Comment: Maybe dig a bit before asking such general question.

Answer (score 0):

To do that:

- Use Templates... > Recording, see [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building)
- Add the generated certificate to your browser following this [documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).
- Record the thing you want to do on google

-You'll end up with :

- An HTTP Request for Google Homepage
- An HTTP Request for the search
- To variabilize the Searched words, add a [CSV Data Set](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)
- Add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) to check the image
- Use a [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to check everything is working